# How to make distance between dot and text in a unordered list smaller?

Tags: html, css

I am using list style image to show dots for an unordered list. They are appearing a little far from text and i want to make the distance between the list text and dot a little less. I have tried padding and margin but nothing seems to work. Can somebody please suggest something.

Comment: Did you try padding and margin on the li elements or the ul element?

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle with a snippet?

Comment: li{
  padding-left:10px;  
} a postive padding left is working it makes the dot far from the text. But i want to bring them closer so negative padding left is not working.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try a negative [`text-indent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-indent) on the `<li>`:

```
li {
    text-indent: -5px;
}
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QgNxw/

Browser support might be a bit dodgy (e.g. Opera and WebKit don't render that fiddle the same way). You could also try using the [`:before` pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/generate.html#before-after-content) to add your own bullet:

```
.closer {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.closer:before {
    content: '•';
    margin-right: 3px;
}
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eXxzH/

But then you'll have trouble with browsers that don't understand `:before`; but everyone but [IE7 and older understand](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t15) `:before` so that might not be an issue.

If CSS3 is okay, you might be able to do something with the [`::marker` pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#marker-pseudoelement).

There isn't that much fine grained control over how the bullets for a list item are rendered.

Comment: @sushil: Then you're probably stuck with images and putting the spacing in the image itself. Or just live with how the browser wants to render the `<li>` bullets.

Comment: It looks like there is no solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML:

- hi wolrd
- 123
- pay
- see you

css:

```
ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
ul li{ padding:0 0 0 10px; background:url(...) 0px 6px no-repeat; list-style-type:none;}
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that i do not want to use background property for the dots. I can just use list-style-image or list-style-type property.

Comment: You put ul{list-style-image:url(....);
list-style-position:outside;
list-style-type:disc;}

Answer (score 0):

You could put divs inside your li elements and set their left margins to something negative:

```
li > div {
    margin-left:-4px;
}
```

Comment: I do not have control over the html. The html is generated from some content entry source. I can just write the css.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is really old but you can use `list-style-position: inside` and then add whatever padding or margin you need on the list itself.